# Mime type optimisation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, optimization

I want to solve the mime challenge in coding games.com. My code can pass all the test but not the optimisation test.

I tried to remove all useless functions like parsing to string but the problem is on the way I think about it.

```py
import sys
import math



# Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
# the standard input according to the problem statement.

n = int(input())  # Number of elements which make up the association table.
q = int(input())
# Number Q of file names to be analyzed.
dico = {}

# My function

def check(word):
    for item in dico:
        if(word[-len(item)-1:].upper() == "."+item.upper()):
            return(dico[item])
    return("UNKNOWN")



for i in range(n):
    # ext: file extension
    # mt: MIME type.
    ext, mt = input().split()
    dico[ext] = mt


for i in range(q):
    fname = input()
    fname = fname
    print(check(fname))


# Write an action using print
# To debug: print("Debug messages...", file=sys.stderr)
#print("Debug message...", file=sys.stderr)
```

Failure
Process has timed out. This may mean that your solution is not optimized enough to handle some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right idea, but one detail appears to be destroying the performance. The problem is the line `for item in dico:`, which unnecessarily loops over every entry in the [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). This is a linear search O(n), checking for the target item-by-item. But this pretty much defeats the purpose of the dictionary data structure, which is to offer constant-time O(1) lookups. "Constant time" means that no matter how big the dictionary gets, the time it takes to find an item is always the same (thanks to [hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)).

To draw a metaphor, imagine you're looking for a spoon in your kitchen. If you know where all the utensils, appliances and cookware are are ahead of time, you don't need to look in every drawer to find the utensils. Instead, you just go straight to the utensils drawer containing the spoon you want, and it's one-shot!

On the other hand, if you're in someone else's kitchen, it can be difficult to find a spoon. You have to start at one end of the cupboard and check every drawer until you find the utensils. In the worst-case, you might get unlucky and have to check every drawer before you find the utensil drawer.

Back to the code, the above snippet is using the latter approach, but we're dealing with trying to find something in 10k unfamiliar kitchens each with 10k drawers. Pretty slow, right?

If you can adjust the solution to check the dictionary in constant time, without a loop, then you can handle `n = 10000` and `q = 10000` without having to make `q * n` iterations (you can do it in `q` iterations instead--so much faster!).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help,
I figured out the solution.

```
n = int(input())  # Number of elements which make up the association table.
q = int(input())  # Number Q of file names to be analyzed.
dico = {}

# My function
def check(word):
    if("." in word):
        n = len(word)-(word.rfind(".")+1)
        extension = word[-n:].lower()
        if(extension in dico):
            return(dico[extension])
    return("UNKNOWN")


for i in range(n):
    # ext: file extension
    # mt: MIME type.
    ext, mt = input().split()
    dico[ext.lower()] = mt

for i in range(q):
    fname = input()
    print(check(fname))
```

Your explanation was clear :D
Thank you